# How to restart docker containers(in specific order) automatically on every reboot in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have two containers in Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS and I want them to restart automatically on unexpected reboots. I have the below script, that restarts only one container. My requirement is to restart both the containers with time gap of 2 minutes. How do I do that?

My /etc/init/service-name.conf script now looks like this:

description "service description"
author "me"
start on filesystem and started docker
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
script
    /usr/bin/docker start -a db5e61a9afa8
end script

Regards,
Suresh